# jquery code not working in chrome whereas working in firefox , anonymous function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a font picker. Everything is working fine on Firefox but on chrome the select function is not getting called on the change event of the select box.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y8ppa4zc/3/

The code is like this

```
(function( $ ) {

var settings;

var methods = {
init : function(options) {

  settings = $.extend( {
    'hide_fallbacks' : false,
    'selected' : function(style) {},
    'initial' : '',
    'fonts' : []
  }, options);

  var root = this;
  root.callback = settings['selected'];
  var visible = false;
  var selected = false;

  var displayName = function(font) {
    if (settings['hide_fallbacks'])
      return font.substr(0, font.indexOf(','));
    else
      return font;
  }

  var select = function(font) {
    //root.append('<option value="'+displayName(font).replace(/["']{1}/gi,"")+'">'+displayName(font).replace(/["']{1}/gi,"")+ '</option>');
    //root.css('font-family', font);
    selected = font;
    root.callback(selected);
  }



  // Setup markup
  $(this).append('<option value="'+settings['initial'].replace(/'/g,'&#039;')+'">' + settings['initial'].replace(/'/g,'&#039;') + '</option>');



  for (var i = 0; i < settings['fonts'].length; i++) {
    var item = $('<optgroup><option value="'+displayName(settings['fonts'][i])+'">' + displayName(settings['fonts'][i]) + '</option></optgroup>').appendTo(this);
    $(item).css('font-family', settings['fonts'][i]);
  }

  if (settings['initial'] != '')
    select(settings['initial']);

  $(this).click(function() {
    //select($(this).val());
  });

  $(this).change(function(event) {

    select($(this).val());
  });


},
selected : function() {
  return $(this).val();
},
select : function(font) {
    font = $(this).val();
    selected = font;
  }
  };

  $.fn.fontSelector = function(method) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.fontSelector' );
    }
  }
}) ( $ );


$('#fontSelect').fontSelector({
            'hide_fallbacks' : true,
            'initial' : 'Courier New,Courier New,Courier,monospace',
            'selected' : function(style) { alert("S1: " + style); },
            'fonts' : [
                'Arial,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif',
                'Arial Black,Arial Black,Gadget,sans-serif',
                'Comic Sans MS,Comic Sans MS,cursive',
                'Courier New,Courier New,Courier,monospace',
                'Georgia,Georgia,serif',
                'Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif',
                'Lucida Console,Monaco,monospace',
                'Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Grande,sans-serif',
                'Palatino Linotype,Book Antiqua,Palatino,serif',
                'Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif',
                'Times New Roman,Times,serif',
                'Trebuchet MS,Helvetica,sans-serif',
                'Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif',
                'Gill Sans,Geneva,sans-serif'
                ]
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width:300px;margin:100px auto;">
        <select id="fontSelect" class="fontSelect">
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in chrome and firefox

Comment: Me too. Chrome 37, Win7

Comment: And Chrome 38 now it updated :)